# TaskStackBuilder getPendingIntent method doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

Unsure what the specific issue is, but the below code halts before it finishes and does not make it to `Log.d("debug", "debug 2.4.3");`.

```
    NotificationCompat.Action actionViewContact, actionCreateActivity;

    Class createContact = ViewContactsActivity.class;
    Class viewContacts  = ViewContactsActivity.class;
    Class createActivity= CreateActivityActivity.class;

    //Activities to launch via notifications
    Intent createContactIntent  = new Intent(context, createContact);
    Intent viewContactsIntent   = new Intent(context, viewContacts);
    Intent createActivityIntent = new Intent(context, createActivity);

    //Put Extras
    createContactIntent.putExtra(ViewContactsActivity.CREATE_CONTACT_KEY, true);
    createContactIntent.putExtra(ViewContactsActivity.ANI_KEY, ani);
    createContactIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.ONSTART_KEY, MainActivity.ONSTART_CREATE_CONTACT);

    viewContactsIntent.putExtra(ViewContactsActivity.CONTACTS_KEY, (ArrayList)contacts);
    viewContactsIntent.putExtra(ViewContactsActivity.ANI_KEY, ani);
    viewContactsIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.ONSTART_KEY, MainActivity.ONSTART_VIEW_CONTACTS);

    createActivityIntent.putExtra(CreateActivityActivity.CONTACT_KEY, contacts.get(0));
    createActivityIntent.putExtra(CreateActivityActivity.ANI_KEY, contacts.get(0));
    createActivityIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.ONSTART_KEY, MainActivity.ONSTART_CREATE_ACTIVITY);

    //Add backstack, so that back button results in returning to MainActivity.class
    TaskStackBuilder sbCreateContact  = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    TaskStackBuilder sbViewContacts   = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    TaskStackBuilder sbCreateActivity = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

    sbCreateContact.addParentStack(createContact).addNextIntent(createContactIntent);
    sbViewContacts.addParentStack(viewContacts).addNextIntent(viewContactsIntent);
    sbCreateActivity.addParentStack(createActivity).addNextIntent(createActivityIntent);

    //Create pending intents for notification actions
    int piFlag = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
    Log.d("debug", "debug 2.4.1");
    PendingIntent piCreateContact = sbCreateContact.getPendingIntent(0, piFlag);
    Log.d("debug", "debug 2.4.2");
    PendingIntent piViewContacts  = sbViewContacts.getPendingIntent(0, piFlag);
    Log.d("debug", "debug 2.4.3");
    PendingIntent piCreateActivity= sbCreateActivity.getPendingIntent(0, piFlag);
    Log.d("debug", "debug 2.4.4");
```

I am trying to look deeper into it, but this is certainly an odd bug.

Comment: Look in your logcat for the crash and stacktrace.

Comment: Might have something to do with `    viewContactsIntent.putExtra(ViewContactsActivity.CONTACTS_KEY, (ArrayList)contacts);`

Comment: @David, I think you're right. Also, there is no stack trace. Which is the weird part.

Comment: Are you filtering the logcat? If so, you are probably missing the crash and stacktrace.

Comment: contacts is an instance of ArrayList<Contact> and Contact with a class which implements Serializable. I will try to run it again and turn off my filtering.

Comment: you were right, I was being a novice. Contact now implements Parcelable and everything works great. Very odd that there was no stacktrace though...

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept the answer. This will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. It resided in the line `viewContactsIntent.putExtra(ViewContactsActivity.CONTACTS_KEY, (ArrayList)contacts);`. If you bundle and object improperly into an intent then try to call `getPendingIntent()`, the program will crash and fail to display a bug report/logs. I crawled through the source code and found several empty catch blocks.

The actual solution involved having Contact class implement Parcable properly.